# CCC 2016: Circle of Life

Tags: code-golf, cellular-automata

## Before I begin, this challenge was not mine originally

Credits to The University of Waterloo. This came from the Canadian Computing Competition 2016, Senior Problem 5. Here is a clickable link to the contest PDF:

[`http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2016/stage%201/seniorEn.pdf`](http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2016/stage%201/seniorEn.pdf)

Here is a link to the site:

[`http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests.html`](http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests.html)

## Challenge

Given a wrapping array of two constant values, determine the configuration after `n` evolutions for positive integer input `n`. These two values represent a living cell and a dead cell. Evolutions work like this:

## Evolution!

After each iteration, a cell is alive if it had exactly one living neighbor in the previous iteration. Any less and it dies of loneliness; any more and it dies of overcrowding. The neighbourhood is exclusive: i.e. each cell has two neighbours, not three.

For example, let's see how `1001011010` would evolve, where `1` is a living cell and `0` is a dead cell.

```
(0) 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 (1)
    *   $         %
```

The cell at the `*` has a dead cell on both sides of it so it dies of lonliness.
The cell at the `$` has a living cell on one side of it and a dead cell on the other. It becomes alive.
The cel at the `%` has a living cell on both sides of it so it stays dead from overcrowding.

## Winning Criteria

Shortest code wins.

## I/O

Input will be a list of the cell states as two consistent values, and an integer representing the number of inputs, in some reasonable format. Output is to be a list of the cell states after the specified number of iterations.

## Test Cases

```
start, iterations -> end
1001011010, 1000 -> 1100001100
100101011010000, 100 -> 000110101001010
0000000101011000010000010010001111110100110100000100011111111100111101011010100010110000100111111010, 1000 -> 1001111111100010010100000100100100111010010110001011001101010111011011011100110110100000100011011001
```

[Test Case](https://hastebin.com/zofexitizo.txt)
[This test case froze hastebin and exceeded the size limit on pastebin](https://alexander-liao.firebaseapp.com/insane-test-case.html)

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged as code golf if byte count is merely a tiebreaker. I'm also not sure if it is a good tiebreaker, as the contest will degenerate to a code golf competition if you can simply port answers to a more concise language to win.

Comment: @Dennis Right, I will remove the tag. What do you suggest for tiebreaking then; earliest submission is another one of my ideas.

Comment: A naive method can *easily* do 10^4 cells 10^4 times in 1 second. 10^8 bitwise operations is nothing.

Comment: I'm voting as unclear for the moment since it's unknowable what is meant by complexity when there are multiple parameters.

Comment: I haven't really analyzed it but I suspect it's also too trivial for a [tag:fastest-algorithm].

Comment: Does a cell count as its own neighbor?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes; sorry, I fixed that. I was having markdown troubles with such a long line.

Comment: @Zgarb No, it does not.

Comment: @feersum Thank you for your feedback. I decided to change it to a [tag:code-golf] instead because it doesn't have much room for optimizations.

Comment: Your [hastebin test case](https://hastebin.com/yuwayayobo.txt) claims to give the MD5 hash with a trailing newline, but actually gives the MD5 hash without a trailing newline. I cannot figure out how to make the hash match either way on your [firebaseapp test case](https://alexander-liao.firebaseapp.com/insane-test-case.html). Can you check that again?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Oh, hm, that's strange. I'll update the description. And I'll need to get back to a computer (not this chromebook) for the insane test case because i can't update from my chromebook, so I'll get back to you on that one. Thanks!

Comment: @feersum, there is a tiny bit of play in [tag:fastest-algorithm]. The naïve algorithm takes `Theta(nt)` where `n` is the length of the array and `t` is the number of evolutions; a faster algorithm takes `Theta(n lg t)`.

Comment: I've created a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59536/circle-of-life-optimizations) where we can discuss optimized algorithms further.

Comment: I think your description of alive/dead = 1/0 could do with improving. I had to read the pdf to fully understand the challenge, which is fine until the link dies. You should have all the info in your question.

Comment: @Notts90 I hope my latest edit clarifies it more.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino yes much clearer :)

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I think I've fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/),14 bytes

Prompts for start state as Boolean list and then for number of iterations

```apl
(1∘⌽≠¯1∘⌽)⍣⎕⊢⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdObMoOSf1v4bho44Zj3r2PupccGg9lK35qHfxo76pj7oWAUmQ2v8KYADRwmWoYACEhmAMIQ24DA0MDLhwqkJSCYEg9ajKDRSQIao2hBgq2xDOQ0CEnCFWPaiqDeE2oOpHZhmgeRfVBWg2gwMCAA)

`⎕` numeric prompt (for Boolean list of start state)

`⊢` on that, apply

`(`…`)⍣⎕` the following tacit function, numeric-prompt times

`¯1∘⌽` the argument rotated one step right

`≠` different from (XOR)

`1∘⌽` the argument rotated one step left

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ṙ2^ṙ-µ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w50yjOCChe2jroYX//7tWFKQml6SmKOSXlhSUllgpGBgYGBoagCCY@B9tqGMAhIZwDGOBYex/oDoA)

[Extra Test Case (footer for formatting)](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w50yjOCChe2jroYX/iw0PL//vWlGQmlySmqKQX1pSUFpipWBoYGAIBQZAJgiBGFCmAUQaKg5RYQgWA6sDS0ERVBRJO5RvYPhfycAAKgg1BcUOqAMMYOYitMMdBpWHWmuAbAxcs9J/kBAA).

**Explanation**

```
ṙ2^ṙ-µ¡
     µ¡  - repeat a number of times equal to input 2:
ṙ2         - previous iteration rotated 2 to the left
  ^        - XOR-ed with:
           - (implicit) previous iteration
   ṙ-      - rotate back (by negative 1 to the left)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
FDÀÀ^Á
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@/mcrjhcEPc4cb//w0NDAy4og10FDCRISppiE0Wq4ghqiAaQlNpSMg0rIYYojoJq/mYXEyvGeL2AnZnxwIA)

**Explanation**

```
F        # input_1 times do
 D       # duplicate last iteration (input_2 the first iteration)
  ÀÀ     # rotate left twice
    ^    # XOR
     Á   # rotate right
```